# Is it possible to configure specific per profile sample rate and format in Pulseaudio/ALSA?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

0

I have a sound card/dac/amp (Sennheiser GSX1000) that has two very different profiles: one of them is a 7.1 surround sound that works if and only if the sample format is 16 bits/48khz lower; while the other one, 2.0 HD audio, only works if the config is at least 24 bit/96000khz.

As each one of the configurations invalidate the other one, I created a mapping and profile for each of these two sound profiles in a .conf file in /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/, and the way I switch profiles now is by editing the default-sample-rate and default-sample-format in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and then reloading pulseaudio (pulseaudio -k), which is kinda bothering.

I would like to know if is there a way to set specific sample-rate and format for each profile instead of a whole sound card in some config file, so the switch is smoother and more natural.

I have thought of other solutions like creating a daemon that subscribes to pulseaudio events and then detect the profile change, check the selected profile, go change the files and restart the pulseaudio daemon, but I would leave that as the last option.

Comment: I'm looking for the same, I recently take a repo as based and create this configuration https://github.com/rkmax/sennheiser-gsx-1000 which work very nice and looking for enable 2.0 HD sound without need to change the daemon

Comment: @rkmax did your GSX1000 turn on the HD lights at the right side of the 2.0? please read the issue I opened about a month ago in the evilphish repo (the repo you forked from) for a more detailed explanation of the problem https://github.com/evilphish/sennheiser-gsx-1000/issues/13

Comment: Yes the HD light turn on my device when I change sample rate/format on demon.conf but I cannot change this using profiles which is what I want

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/QXpcAmNs135YcquCA